# Do they always hide implementation files?

Tags: core-animation

I am getting started with CoreAnimation and want to know more about some of the implementations. Where (if possible) can I find the implementation files?

This is my first go with a proprietary framework (I come from web world) so I guess it makes sense for them to be off-limits.

I mean, the .h and docs are OK, but it would be nice to see what's actually happening!

This seems like such a stupid question, but I just want to make sure that I'm not missing something painfully obvious: I'm not supposed to see how they actually do things, am I? It's just... what if I want to over-ride something and can't see how it's done?

Comment: Uhh, do you know anything about Apple?

Comment: I like using money from the bank, can someone tell me where to get the printing plates?

Comment: I know they make cool products. Starting to see the 'dark side'. :P

Comment: @mikerobi Hahaha... nice one. Well I knew it was as stupid question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very few of Apple's frameworks are open-source. For the most part, if something is meant to be overridden, the documentation will contain the information you need to do it. There are a few rough edges, but that's generally the way it is. You shouldn't, ideally, need to see the implementation details — they are subject to change anyway. It's a sign of bad library design if you actually need to read a method's implementation to use it (not to say that it wouldn't be nice to have the source, but clients of the library shouldn't *need* it).

If you really like having the source to everything, Linux or BSD might interest you. (I personally don't feel the tradeoff in usability is worth it, but your mileage may vary.)

Comment: Actually, I had this question because I am looking at one method of NSView -(CALayer*)layer which 'returns the CALayer that is the backing store for the view', and am wondering whether its already created or the method creates and returns it. Here's the thing: it has no practical effect on anything, because of course there is no memory problem with their frameworks. But you see, I am just curious how everything works in it! So... yeah, I will deal with the closed nature of it, but maybe I will get into another open-source language to satisfy my inner engineer... Thanks BTW, a stupid question!